# why hibernate forcing serialization in session.get method

Tags: java, hibernate

I see that hibernate's session.get() and load() methods is accepting only Serializable objects.

As per my understanding of hibernate, it will generate an SQL statement and send it to DBMS.  It will never need to send a java object over network.

Why hibernate is forcing serialization on us?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, the fact that Hibernate uses `Serializable` in some signature doesn't mean that Hibernate **will** serialize anything, it just means that parameters are serializable if the need arises.

Then, I couldn't find an absolute reference but I think that the strongest argument is:

- Entities Ids are use as key for caching (first level, second level) and may be send over the wire

Some weaker arguments (or not argument at all):

- The `Session` itself can be potentially serialized (e.g. to be stored in the `HttpSession`)
- Hibernate needs a super type for `entityId` (including composite PK)

Given all this, I think it makes sense to enforce users of the API to pass a `Serializable entityId`, this allows to not close any door and to avoid any later limitation (oops, you can't activate second level caching because this pk is not `Serializable`). This is IMO a much better design decision than using `Object`. And to be honest, I do not see any annoyance with that.

Comment: I have really no problem with using Serializable.  But my point is why somebody else has to force something on me, even if it is very good practice?

Answer (score 2):

This is not quite true. [From the Javadoc](http://ajava.org/online/hibernate3api/org/hibernate/Session.html), the signature of the relevant methods is:

```
public Object get(Class clazz, Serializable id) ...
public Object load(Class theClass, Serializable id) ...
```

(irrelevant parts and other overloaded versions omitted for brevity).

So the entity to be loaded can be of any class, only its identifer needs to be serializable.

Entities indeed net not be serializable, as per this quote from [Java Persistence with Hibernate](http://www.manning.com/bauer2/), ch. 13.3.2:

> Persistent instances are stored in the second-level cache in a disassembled
>   form. Think of disassembly as a process a bit like serialization (the algorithm is
>   much, much faster than Java serialization, however).

So I would guess the identifiers (in the query cache) are also not serialized. I could not find any explanation on why `id` is declared `Serializable`, and lacking this, I can only guess. The API needs a type for the `id` parameter, which should be a common supertype of at least the frequently used identifier types `Number` and `String`, and apart from `Object`, `Serializable` is the only choice.

Comment: true, but why even Identifier has to be serializable?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the support for caching. When using a persistent cache, or any caching that distributes object via network you need to have a way of making sure the objects can be transported in a common format which, in this case, is Java serialization.

Comment: but is this caching over multiple JVMs default option?
I think it is not, and if I am configuring cache or cluster I would make my objects serializable.

But why hibernate has to force me to use Serialization when I am not using any distributed cache?

Comment: No, it's not enabled by default. I would guess that enforcing Serializable implementation should make a developer recognize that a value object might be subject to serialization and therefore should be designed in that way.

Just a guess, I've never really thought about it and didn't even recognize it until I've read your question.

Answer (score 0):

I frankly don't see it any other way. If you are not the one defining table structure and generating insert statements to accommodate for objects, then the SQL statement generated is a string in itself and it would insert another string of text (your serialized data) into a field of a table. Whatever you insert into a database has to be a string in this case, it cannot be an object with language dependent methods, unless you explicitly design an table to store data like that.

Comment: 1. get() and load() does not insert anything into the table, just retrieves an existing entity, 2. the whole point of Hibernate is object-relational mapping (ORM), i.e. that the properties of the object are mapped to table columns one by one (more or less) in an explicitly designed fashion. No serialization happens by default, unless you explicitly define it (and you probably need a custom mapping type for this).

Comment: Good point. I misinterpreted your question. However, I've used these before for storing references, i.e. ids for objects, so the serialization made sense as a storage approach. My experience may be a bit limited in this case.