# Using hibernate's session.get() with a long ID

Tags: java, hibernate

I would like to use IDs of type `long` for my persisted objects. However, I find that get() method requires a Serializable object as its ID parameter ([discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012660/why-hibernate-forcing-serialization-in-session-get-method)). What is the best workaround?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `Long`. Hibernate will do the correct mapping for you. And if you use Java 5, you can

```
long id = ...;
session.get (id);
```

and the compiler will do the rest.

Comment: Great! This completes my first integration test using hibernate. It took several hours, but I can finally persist and read an entity!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 5/6 it should do that for you with autoboxing. However i would recommend using Long instead of long so that it evaluates to null and not zero.